# How do I loop through array and call function for each?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that I need to loop through, and for specific keys, I then need to call chopActNum function. The function takes an account number, and turns it into the "xxxxxxxxxx1234" format. I would like to then display this new format rather than the whole account number. My `$accountList` holds all the information for the accounts. My confusion is in that I currently display all my account information through assignment in Smarty templating. I am horrible at explaining, so perhaps seeing my code will help elucidate my issue.
My function:

```
public function chopActNum($actNum=0){

    $numPlace=strlen($actNum)-4;
    $repeatX=str_repeat('x',$numPlace);
    $actNumConcat=$repeatX.substr($actNum, -4); 
    return $actNumConcat;
```

Php:

```
foreach($achList as $a)
{
$actNum[] = $a['actNum'];
$chopNum=$Ach->chopActNum($actNum);
}

$achList=$Ach->listAch($logged_userid);
$smarty->assign("accountList",$achList);
```

Tpl Code:

```
{foreach from=$accountList item=v name=foo} 
<td class="tableData">{$v.actName}</td>
<td class="tableData">{$v.actNum}</td>
<td class="tableData">{$v.bankRoute}</td>
{/foreach}
```

Comment: How do you know if it's one of the specific keys that should call `chopActNum`?

Comment: I don't understand. In your php code you are getting a $chopNum but you are never doing anything with it. Don't you want to be doing something like:
`$a['chopNum'] = $chopNum`
or 
`$a['actNum'] = $chopNum`
inside your loop? And, if you do, remember to put the & reference marker  on $a, that is:
`foreach($achList as &$a)`
or you change the contents of $a in the loop but the change isn't returned when the loop is finished.

Comment: I ended up finding a solution over the weekend, but thank you everyone for your help!     for ($x=0; $x < count($achList); $x++){
   
   $actNum=text_decrypt($achList[$x]['actNum']);   
   $chopNum=$Ach->chopActNum($actNum);
    $achList[$x]['accountNumDisplay']=$chopNum;
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use array_map to prepare the data for your template like this:

```
$achList = arrar_map(function($v){
  return array(
    'actName' => $v['actName'],
    'actNum' => chopActNum($v['actNum']),
    'bankRoute' => $v['bankRoute']
  );
}, $achList);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the key in `foreach`, and then check if it's one of the specific keys.

```
$specific_keys = array(...);
foreach ($achList as $key => $acct) {
    if (in_array($key, $specific_keys)) {
        $actNum[] = chopActNum($acct['actNum']);
    } else {
        $actNum[] = $acct['actNum'];
    }
}
```